# How to stop 'tap' event firing on the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem I need help with as I am a bit new to Jquery, what I have is a button which is half hidden at the left side of the screen and a menu which is completely hidden from view also at the left side, what I am trying to achieve is, on mobile the user would 'tap' the button which would slide from the side to reveal the full button for which then you would tap the button again which would then slide the menu out from its hidden position on the left. The problem I am having is no matter which approach I take, whenever I tap the half hidden button, it will slide out but then the menu slides out straight away without having to tab the button a second time so if any of you kind folk could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
$( "#catbutt" ).on("tap",function(e) {
    $( "#catbutt" ).animate({left: "0px"},300,'swing');
});

$( "#catbutt" ).on("tap",function(e) {
    $( "#categories" ).animate({left: "0px"});
});
```

Comment: IIRC, the code in both will fire at the same time...

Comment: Please share your HTML & CSS too!

Comment: You have two diferent tasks to perform at different times, on `tap`. **1)** To reveal the full button. **2)** To slide the menu. -- Post a [minimal **BUT** Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you defining the conditions. -- As @JackBashford said, both handlers are firering on each `tap` events... The way you coded it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, where you check the `#catbutt` element's left position, and if it's already 0px, slide out the `#categories` element, otherwise, just slide out the `#catbutt` element (heh. catbutt.) :

```
$( "#catbutt" ).on("tap",function(e) {
  if($(this).css('left') == '0px') {
    $( "#categories" ).animate({left: "0px"});
  }
  else {
    $(this).animate({left: "0px"}, 300, 'swing');
  }
});
```

You're still going to have to get it to close, too. Here's a Fiddle with it having three stages... the first is the button expanding, the second is the menu expanding, and the third is both the button and menu collapsing: https://jsfiddle.net/wcvg3nby/

Here's the pertinent code from the Fiddle:

CSS

```
#catbutt {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -80px;
  background-color: red;
}

#categories {
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='catbutt'></div>

<div id='categories'>
  <div>Cat 1</div>
  <div>Cat 2</div>
  <div>Cat 3</div>
  <div>Cat 4</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#catbutt').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).offset().left < 0) {
    $(this).animate({'left':'0px'});
  }
  else if($(this).offset().left == 0) {
    $(this).animate({left: '100px'});
    $('#categories').animate({left: '0px'});
  }
  else {
    $(this).animate({left: '-80px'});
    $('#categories').animate({left: '-100px'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark, that works perfectly for what I require, and the answer was so simple but yet effective, how did I not see that lol

Comment: @AndyHowe No problem. If you get a chance to mark it as the accepted answer, I'd be grateful. See ya around.